# Root login with ssh without password

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

I have a linux server and a list with ssh keys of the authenticated users. Now after connecting to the ssh, the users must use `sudo -i` to login as root, in order to do their things. Only few people have access to the ssh so this password for the root is not needed in my case, they should be able to login as root without typing any password.

What I did is I added following Line to my `sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

I also checked the sudoers file and this line is in it:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
some_user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

`some_user` ist the user they login as when accessing the ssh.

This didn't do anything. So i restarted the service and restartet the whole system (`sudo reboot`) but nothing helped, it still asks for the password everytime the user excecutes `sudo -i`

Comment: SO is for programming problems. Please try  [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) or [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: ssh (remote connection) has nothing to do with local sudo. Also it is not clear what your goal is, for `some_user` to execute sudo commands without password? does `sudo su` work without a password for `some_user` ?

Comment: @Ron sorry if I haven't make it clear. some_user cannot `sudo su` without password. I just want everybody to have access to the SSH to have sudo rights on the server

Comment: add them to a group, as per the example above group `admin`  `Members of the admin group may gain root privileges` or `sudo` group `to execute any command`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want some users to be able to ssh into your server and become root without them typing a password?

If that's all you want, you don't need sudo at all.

Instead, add their ssh public key to the root user's authorized_keys file (typically /root/.ssh/authorized_keys)

Then your users can login as root without a password with "ssh **root**@your_server.com" instead of "ssh **ilian**@your_server.com"

(and yes, you also need the /etc/ssh/sshd_config item you mention - PermitRootLogin without-password).

If the directory does not exist, create it but make sure the permissions and ownership are correct..
It must look like this:

```
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar 31  2022 /root/.ssh/
```

This can be achieved by performing (as root):

```
mkdir -m 700 /root/.ssh
```